# Flutter how to get the widgets by the navigator

Tags: flutter, widget, navigator

I need to collect information about the elements of the page when the page is displayed. How can I get all the information about the elements of the page after push.

like this:

```
  @override
  void onPagePush(Route route) {
    super.onPagePush(route);
     
    //top widget
    Widget widget = route.navigator?.overlay?.widget;
    

    List<Widget> widgetList = [];

    for(int i = 0; i<widget.childCount; i++){
      widgetList.add(widget.getChildren(i));
    }
    ...
  }
```